# JavaScript: How can i make my traffic light sequence from a button to automated?

Tags: javascript

I have created a script to change traffic lights on click of a button. However I would like to change it so it is automated. I am quite new to coding so I would appreciate it if anybody could help me or create it for me. I will leave my current script below. Once again if anybody can help I would much appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3 Traffic Lights </h1>

<img id=”light” src=”"H:/Year 11/Computer Science/A452 Practical Investigation/Task 3 - Code/assets/redlight.jpg">

<button type=”button” onclick=”changeLights()”>Change Lights</button>

<script>
var list = [
"H:/Year 11/Computer Science/A452 Practical Investigation/Task 3 - Code/assets/redlight.jpg",
"H:/Year 11/Computer Science/A452 Practical Investigation/Task 3 - Code/assets/redamberlight.jpg",
"H:/Year 11/Computer Science/A452 Practical Investigation/Task 3 - Code/assets/greenlight.jpg",
"H:/Year 11/Computer Science/A452 Practical Investigation/Task 3 - Code/assets/amberlight.jpg"
 ];

var index = 0;
function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) index = 0;
    var image = document.getElementById(‘light’);

    image.src=list[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to the (good) answer given by czosel, it's worth pointing out that absolute addresses are rarely a good thing when dealing with files hosted and run locally (i.e, on your own machine). Relative URLs are far easier to maintain - they're shorter too. Presumably, you have an HTML file that exists inside `H:\Year 11\Computer Science\A542 Practical Investigation\Task 3 - Code`. Inside that folder along with the html file, you also have a folder named `assets`. If this is the case, you can simply refer to the images thusly: `assets/redlight.jpg`, `assets/greenLight.jpg` etc, etc (cont)

Comment: By doing this, you can copy the whole contents of the folder - the html file and the assets folder along with its images to a different location without modification - you could run it from a usb stick or the desktop or wherever. You could even drop it into an online server as is - no further modification needed. Here's an MSDN page that explains the idea in greater detail: [Understanding Absolute and Relative URL Addresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208688(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "automate" you mean switching the traffic light automatically in a certain interval. This can be done easily with the help of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

```
setInterval(changLights, 1000);
```

The first parameter is the function that you want to execute periodically, 
and the second one is the interval in milliseconds - so in this example the lights would change every second.

Minimal example:

```js
index = 0;

function change() {
  index += 1;
  console.log(index);
}

setInterval(change, 1000);
```